# How to reach the geometry (polygon, polyline) of a dxf in python-ogr module

Tags: python, ogr

this might be a basic question, but I am rather new in ogr. I wish to collect all lines from the dxf file and create their boundary. I loaded the layers (ExecuteSQL( "SELECT DISTINCT Layer FROM entities" )); and would like to put every line in a new layer, but it seems that I cannot reach the geometry of the layers. I tried to use layers.GetFeature().GetGeometry() in a for, but it is not working.

Comment: Elaborate on "is not working". And by "boundary", do you expect a potentially irregular polygon, or a bounding box extent?

Comment: a potentially irregular polygon, I can reach the layers by GetFeature, but their geometry not. Thanks